# chef attribute will not get over ridden

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, vagrantfile, chef-solo

I am running a recipe that depends on multiple recipes, one of which tries to clone a github repo and gives the url as an attribute in its cookbook in attributes/fair.rb (https://github.com/priestjim/chef-openresty/blob/master/attributes/fair.rb) :

```
# For more information checkout https://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair
default['openresty']['fair']['url']             = 'git://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git'
```

I need to over ride this attribute to give the https endpoint in stead of SSH so in my cookbook , I create attributes/fair.rb and put down:

```
override['openresty']['fair']['url'] = 'https://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git'
```

but when I run chef solo using vagrant, it fails with following:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:     ------------------------------------
==> default:     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
==> default:     ---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git" "master*" ----
==> default:     STDOUT: 
==> default:     STDERR: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
==> default:     github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out
==> default:     ---- End output of git ls-remote "git://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git" "master*" ----
==> default:     Ran git ls-remote "git://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git" "master*" returned 128
==> default:     
==> default:     Resource Declaration:
==> default:     ---------------------
==> default:     # In /tmp/vagrant-chef/97b7f5ef6e972aa934bfb7ea6a5db3bb/cookbooks/openresty/recipes/fair_module.rb
==> default:     
==> default:      26: git module_path do
==> default:      27:   repository node['openresty']['fair']['url']
==> default:      28:   reference 'master'
==> default:      29:   action :checkout
==> default:      30:   not_if { ::File.exists?(module_path) }
==> default:      31: end
==> default:      32: 
==> default:     
==> default:     Compiled Resource:
==> default:     ------------------
==> default:     # Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef/97b7f5ef6e972aa934bfb7ea6a5db3bb/cookbooks/openresty/recipes/fair_module.rb:26:in `from_file'
==> default:     
==> default:     git("/var/chef/cache/nginx-upstream-fair") do
==> default:       action [:checkout]
==> default:       retries 0
==> default:       retry_delay 2
==> default:       default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:       destination "/var/chef/cache/nginx-upstream-fair"
==> default:       enable_checkout true
==> default:       revision "master"
==> default:       remote "origin"
==> default:       checkout_branch "deploy"
==> default:       declared_type :git
==> default:       cookbook_name :openresty
==> default:       recipe_name "fair_module"
==> default:       repository "git://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git"
==> default:       not_if { #code block }
==> default:     end



Ran git ls-remote "git://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git" "master*" returned 128
==> default: [2016-02-23T01:03:00+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

as you can see still takes the ssh endpoint for some reason. Any idea why ?

Comment: Does the run-list include a recipe from your cookbook where the attribute is overridden?

Answer (score 0):

In your wrapper for the openresty cookbook, make sure it depends on openresty in its `metadata.rb`. This will ensure things are loaded in the correct order.